# How to make data-binding between non-child elements work in Polymer

Tags: html, polymer, 2-way-object-databinding

I'm making a remake of [my website](https://charlesmilette.github.io") in Polymer. I'm currently trying to make two-way data binding work, for being able that the corresponding menu element becames selected when an iron-pages becames selected, and vice-versa. The code I'm currently using is:

```
<body class="fullbleed roboto">
    <paper-drawer-panel force-narrow>
        <paper-header-panel mode="standard" main>
            <paper-toolbar class="amber">
                <paper-icon-button icon="menu" paper-drawer-toggle></paper-icon-button>
                <div class="title">Charles Milette's Personnal Website</div>
            </paper-toolbar>
            <iron-pages selected="{{selected}}">
                <div id="content">Home Content</div>
                <div id="content">Page 1 Content</div>
            </iron-pages>
        </paper-header-panel>
        <div drawer>
            <img src="img/drawer.png" />
            <paper-menu selected="{{selected}}">
                <paper-item><iron-icon icon="home"></iron-icon>Home</paper-item>
                <paper-item>Page 1</paper-item>
            </paper-menu>
        </div>
    </paper-drawer-panel>
</body>
```

But, evidentually, it doesn't works, because data bindings only works between child and parent elements, as explained [here](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/data-binding.html#property-binding).
I think [attrForSelected](https://elements.polymer-project.org/elements/iron-pages#property-attrForSelected) may do what I need to, but I'm not sure how to use it.
Using some event listeners to listen for properties change and/or clicks can also do it, but I'm searching for a better way to do it (kinda like data binding).

Is there any better way than that? What is it?
If attrForSelected is what I search, how do I use it?

I'd appreciate if you also give me a code snippet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This answer is essentially the same as Scott's, with a little more explanation of `dom-bind` and an example of how you would change pages from within the main content.

[JS Bin](http://jsbin.com/kurebo/edit?html,output)

```
<body>
  <!-- dom-bind template is the key here. you can use it do declare properties
       at the scope of the template. any polymer elements that are children to
       to the template have access to the template's properties -->
  <template is="dom-bind" id="app">
    <paper-drawer-panel force-narrow>
      <paper-header-panel mode="standard" main>
        <paper-toolbar class="amber">
          <paper-icon-button icon="menu" paper-drawer-toggle></paper-icon-button>
          <div class="title">Website</div>
        </paper-toolbar>
        <!-- attr-for-selected="page" means "when the value of 'selected'
             changes, select the <section> whose 'page' attribute equals
             the value of 'selected' 

             when attr-for-selected is omitted, then 'selected' just
             equals the index of the page

             the 'selected' property is scoped to the dom-bind, so you can think
             of it as document.querySelector('#app').selected 

             you only need one-way data-binding here ('[[selected]]') 
             because <iron-pages> doesn't modify the 'selected' property -->
        <iron-pages attr-for-selected="page" selected="[[selected]]">
          <section page="home">
            <p>value of selected: {{selected}}</p>
            <!-- check out how this ordinary button has access to polymer's 
                 on-* declarative events, thanks to dom-bind! -->
            <button on-tap="about">go to about page</button>
          </section>
          <section page="about">
            <p>value of selected: {{selected}}</p>
            <button on-tap="home">go to home page</button>
          </section>
        </iron-pages>
      </paper-header-panel>
      <div drawer>
        <!-- attr-for-selected works mostly the same here as it did above, 
             with one difference. when you select a <paper-item>, then the 
             'selected' property is set to the value of the 'page' attribute

             you need two-way data binding here ('{{selected}}') because we are
             modifying the value of 'selected'
        -->
        <paper-menu attr-for-selected="page" selected="{{selected}}">
          <paper-item page="home">home</paper-item>
          <paper-item page="about">about</paper-item>
        </paper-menu>
      </div>
    </paper-drawer-panel>
  </template>
  <script>

    // you can access dom-bind properties imperatively, too  
    (function(document) {
      var app = document.querySelector('#app');
      // the app shows the 'about' page first even though it's the second menu 
      // item because we are setting app.selected imperatively when DOM is ready
      app.selected = 'about';
      // changing the selected page is as simply as changing the 
      // value of app.selected
      app.about = function() {
        app.selected = 'about';
      };
      app.home = function() {
        app.selected = 'home';
      };
    }) (document);
  </script>
</body>
```

Comment: I may make iron-pages change the selected content later, but thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Bindings need to be in a `<template>` context. In your case, putting your html inside a `<template is="dom-bind">` will enable binding.

Note that the bindings are between the template and the elements (the elements do not bind directly to each other). This means you aren't violating any rule about parents and children.

```html
<base href="http://polygit.org/components/">

<script src="webcomponentsjs/webcomponents-lite.min.js"></script>
<link href="paper-elements/paper-elements.html" rel="import">
<link href="iron-pages/iron-pages.html" rel="import">

<body class="fullbleed roboto">
  <template is="dom-bind" selected="0">
    <paper-drawer-panel force-narrow>
        <paper-header-panel mode="standard" main>
            <paper-toolbar class="amber">
                <paper-icon-button icon="menu" paper-drawer-toggle></paper-icon-button>
                <div class="title">Charles Milette's Personnal Website</div>
            </paper-toolbar>
            <iron-pages selected="{{selected}}">
                <div id="content">Home Content</div>
                <div id="content">Page 1 Content</div>
            </iron-pages>
        </paper-header-panel>
        <div drawer>
            <paper-menu selected="{{selected}}">
                <paper-item><iron-icon icon="home"></iron-icon>Home</paper-item>
                <paper-item>Page 1</paper-item>
            </paper-menu>
        </div>
    </paper-drawer-panel>
  </template>
</body>
```